# TSQL where on xml data type

Tags: xml, t-sql, where-clause

How does one execute where clause command on a xml data type in Sql Server 2005 ?

#### Xml Structure

```
<User UserId="1" UserName="x">
<User UserId="2" UserName="y">
```

#### Query

```
SELECT XmlColumn from Table where XmlColumn.query('/User[@UserId'+ @dynamicValue +']')
```

#### Intended Output

Get all the user tags where the attribute UserId = input variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  XMLColumn xml
)

insert into @T values ('<User UserId="1" UserName="x"/>')
insert into @T values ('<User UserId="2" UserName="y"/>')

declare @UserID int
set @UserID = 1

select XMLColumn
from @T
where XMLColumn.exist('/User[@UserId = sql:variable("@UserID")]') = 1
```

Result:

```
XMLColumn
---------------------------------
<User UserId="1" UserName="x" />
```

Comment: +1 for making it understandable. btw is there a solution without a SqlVariable involved in it

Comment: Not if you want to have a dynamic way of specifying the UserID. You could of course build the statement dynamically instead and use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).